# Criar .jar de um projeto com vários pacotes, sem IDE e na linha de comando

Tags: java, jar, linha-de-comando, prompt

Ao fazer uma pesquisa pelos sites do [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com), percebi que todos os tópicos só ensinam como criar o arquivo .jar de uma única classe ou então, até ensinavam a criar o .jar de um pacote inteiro, porém sem a finalidade de ser um .jar executável, mas sim uma biblioteca.

A minha necessidade aqui é diferente, eu preciso criar o .jar de um projeto com vários pacotes na linha de comando e esse .jar tem que ser diretamente executável. Criei uma imagem para ilustrar o meu problema, é só seguir a numeração na foto. Eu também descrevo cada etapa logo depois da imagem:

[image: Imagem da criação do código até a geração do .jar]

A pasta raiz do projeto tem o caminho `C:\test`

Etapas:

1 - Mostro o código do arquivo test.java que, em relação ao diretório raiz do projeto, tem caminho `test\src\pack1\test.java`

```
package pack1;

import pack2.*;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(test2.s);
    }
}
```

2 - Mostro o código do arquivo test2.java que, em relação ao diretório raiz do projeto, tem caminho `test\src\pack2\test2.java`

```
package pack2;

public class test2
{
    public static final String s = "20/20";
}
```

3 - Mostro visualmente a estrutura do projeto pelo comando `tree /f`

4 - Compilo os arquivos .java jogando-os na pasta bin com o comando `javac -d bin -cp src src\pack1\test.java`

5 - Mostro visualmente a estrutura do projeto pelo comando `tree /f`

6 - Crio o arquivo .jar com o comando `jar --verbose --create --file test.jar --main-class pack1.test bin`

7 - Mostro visualmente a estrutura do projeto pelo comando `tree /f`

8 - Tento executar o .jar com o comando `java -jar test.jar` e recebo:

```
Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal pack1.test
Causada por: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pack1.test
```

Quando eu faço esse mesmo processo com apenas um .class, eu consigo executar o .jar sem nenhum problema.

Answer (score 1):

Descobri o problema depois de analisar cuidadosamente a solução deste [link](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-how-to-create-executable-fatjar-without-ide). Pelo que vi, o grande problema foi ter adicionado a pasta bin dentro do .jar.

Há duas formas mais simples, na linha de comando, de chegar no resultado que eu queria:

### Formas simples na linha de comando:

Substituir o comando da etapa 6 por:

**Forma 1:**

`cd bin && jar --verbose --create --file ..\test.jar --main-class pack1.test . && cd ..`

ou por:

**Forma 2:**

`jar --verbose --create --file test.jar --main-class pack1.test -C bin .`

Sendo assim, na hora de criar o .jar, o que vai para dentro dele são apenas as pastas que estão dentro da pasta bin, ou seja, as pastas dos pacotes pack1 e pack2. A opção -C do comando jar faz uma mudança temporária de diretório.

[image: Imagem do comando certo juntamente com o teste do .jar]

### Outra forma na linha de comando:

Criar o arquivo manifest.mf com as seguintes linhas:

```
Main-Class: pack1.test
Class-Path: bin/
```

**É importante ressaltar que o Class-Path não funciona se não tiver a [barra sobrando](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548573/does-the-class-path-in-the-manifest-mf-can-only-include-jar-files) depois do nome do diretório, observe que eu escrevi bin/ e não bin**. Além disso, o Class-Path do manifest.mf é relativo a onde ele estiver, ou seja, nesse caso eu criei o arquivo manifest.mf na pasta raiz do projeto e por isso eu pude colocar bin/.

Além disso, o comando da etapa 6 passa a ser:

`jar --verbose --create --file test.jar --manifest manifest.mf bin`

[image: Criação do manifest.mf e teste do .jar pela linha de comando]

Answer (score 0):

```
jar cvfm nomedoarquivo.jar MANIFEST.MF -C pastaProjeto/ .
```

Para mim deu certo desta forma. baseada na forma explicada pelo axell-brendow

- -c ou --create - Cria o arquivo compactado
- -v ou --verbose - Gera saida detalhada no terminal.
- -f ou --file - O nome do arquivo .jar
- -m ou --manifest - Inclui o manifesto.